# Can a binary ++ operator be implemented in Python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, operators

Is it possible to implement a class with the ++ operator in Python, for instance to make `a ++ b` a valid expression?

Answer (score 1):

`a++b` would actually call two operators, but yes, you can do it.

`+b` would call `__pos__`. Then you would `__add__` `+b` to `a`

```
 class K:
    def __pos__(self):
        return self
    def __add__(self, *args):
        return self

a = K()
b = K()

a++b

print(a++b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python interprets `a++b` as `a + (+b)`, so here is one way to implement it by overriding the `__pos__` operator (as long as we weren't going to use it):

```
class Digits(int):
    def __pos__(self):
        class Concat:
            def __init__(self,val):
                self.val = val
            def __radd__(self,lhs):
                return Digits(str(lhs)+str(self.val))
        return Concat(self)
print(Digits(1) + Digits(23))
print(Digits(1) + (+Digits(23)))
print(Digits(1) ++ Digits(23))
```

which gives the following:

```
24
123
123
```